# promises handler

Tags: javascript

Есть ли смысл использовать промисы для построения, к примеру создания какого то блока в DOM`e, при каком либо событии 
Либо проще повесить обработчик, притом же событии и построить новый блок внутри eventListener'а. Так как в любом случае reject скорее всего никогда не возникнет в такой задаче. Подскажите есть ли это резонной задачей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы смешали две абсолютно разные концепции: *События* и *Обещания* (Promises). В то время, как *события* могут быть сгенерированны произвольное число раз *Обещание* должно быть выполнено только однажды. Ну и вы правильно заметили, что в концепции событий нет (и не может быть) аналога `reject` из *Обещаний*.

Таким образом, в описанном случае, вы не должны использовать *Обещания* **вместо** *событий*.